# Add repository branch and configure build on AWS Ampify with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-amplify

I've been trying to host a web app on AWS Amplify by using Terraform. I have used the following code:

```
    # Ressource 1: AWS Amplify
resource "aws_amplify_app" "wildrydes-site" {
  name       = "wildrydes-site"
  repository = "https://github.com/userx/wildrydes-site"
  # GitHub personal access token
  access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
 
  # The default rewrites and redirects added by the Amplify Console.
  custom_rule {
    source = "/<*>"
    status = "404"
    target = "/index.html"
  }

  #Auto Branch Creation
    enable_auto_branch_creation = true

  # The default patterns added by the Amplify Console.
  auto_branch_creation_patterns = [
    "*",
    "*/**",
  ]

  auto_branch_creation_config {
    # Enable auto build for the created branch.
    enable_auto_build = true
  }
```

The resource is actually created, but I have to manually connect my source code from my Git repository and add repository branch. Anyone knows what I have missed ? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, this ended up working for me.  Might have to dissect the why though.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_amplify_app" "example" {
  name         = "blah"
  repository   = "repo here"
  access token = "..."


  environment_variables = {
    ENV = "test"
  }

  # The default rewrites and redirects added by the Amplify Console.
  custom_rule {
    source = "/<*>"
    status = "404"
    target = "/index.html"
  }

  #Auto Branch Creation
  enable_auto_branch_creation = true

  # The default patterns added by the Amplify Console.
  auto_branch_creation_patterns = [
    "*",
    "*/**",
  ]

  auto_branch_creation_config {
    # Enable auto build for the created branch.
    enable_auto_build = true
  }
}

resource "aws_amplify_branch" "master" {
  app_id      = aws_amplify_app.example.id
  branch_name = "main"

  stage = "PRODUCTION"

}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

He added

```
resource "aws_amplify_branch" "master" {
  app_id      = aws_amplify_app.example.id
  branch_name = "main"

  stage = "PRODUCTION"

}
```

This set the `Production branch` in amplify to `main`